# Is there any to open/view/interact with another program in a manner similar to a widget using GTK in C?

Tags: c, gtk

So, in Linux, I'm trying to get a GTK based program to open another program, but instead of opening it in its own window, I want to place it in a new page of a notebook within the first program. I have no idea where to start with this. Anyone ever done something like this before, or have any suggestions?

*edit/update (Jan/14/2017):
I just got back around to messing with the code a little while ago and ran into a roadblock. Let me preface this by saying that: When I started this thing, I knew the absolute basics of c. I could write a fancy hello world with no trouble, but that's about it. I googled my way to this point and I have little idea what I'm actually doing. I'm gonna apologize ahead of time for the overly verbose comments and the wood theme, it's for helping me keep straight how I think it works and is in inside joke respectively.

I've stopped trying to open the programs from within the gtk program for now. Anyway, the idea of this code is that it is supposed to watch for windows that are opened on the desktop, get their id, and use that to place said window into a gtk socket and then put that in a new tab of the notebook. I would prefer to just be able to run it over any existing linux desktop environment that uses X, rather than try to rewrite any of the DE components. I also can't modify the code of the programs that are opening windows on the desktop other than this one. If anyone can tell me why this code doesn't work, it would be really helpful. I will also happily take any coding pointers that people want to provide. As I said, I'm a novice.

I compiled it with this (The apostrophes here are actually supposed to be back-ticks, so **DON'T JUST COPY PASTE THIS!**):
`gcc 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0' -o LogTest logtest.c -lX11 'pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gtk+-x11-3.0 gmodule-2.0'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <X11/Xlibint.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>

#define WOOD "Lumber"

int plywood(int argc, char **argv, int pipe[2])//Not sure what the variables are for, but they are referenced by the gtk initialiser.
{

    close (pipe[1]);//Close the input pipe, sinse we won't be using it.


    //Variables, remember "GtkWidget" acts like a variable type.
    GtkWidget *window_main;//Main window, holds everything.
    GtkWidget *box_main;//Main box, seperates/holds the main notebook.
    GtkWidget *notebook_main;//Main notebook for main things.
    GtkWidget *label_running;//Label for the running notebook.
    GtkWidget *label_open;//
    GtkWidget *notebook_running;//Notebook for running programs.
    GtkWidget *box_running;//Box for containing the running notebook within a tab in the main notebook.
    GtkWidget *ev_box_socket;//This acts to help glue the socket to the box.
    Window xid;//Holds the window id for the program comming from woodglue that we are putting into the running notebook (after some finagling).
    Window check = 0;//Holds the last window id makes sure we are not doing the same thing twice.
    GtkWidget *socket;//This is the thing we stuff the external window into.
    GtkWidget *box_socket;//This holds the socket for input into the other box, to goin the notebook.
    Window plywood = 0;//holds the window id for plywood. it should be the first one to come in.
    GtkWidget *box_placeholder;//This box is a place holder.
    int ftc = 0;//This helps to record what run of the loop we are on.
    double test;

    //Start GTK
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);//Sets the  groundwork for all of the gtk funtions and such.


    //Making Labels
    label_running = gtk_label_new("Open Windows");//Creats a label with the text "Open Windows".

    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(GTK_WIDGET(label_running), TRUE);//Tells the label to expand in thehorizontal direction if it can.

    label_open = gtk_label_new("test");//Creats a label with the text "test".

    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(GTK_WIDGET(label_open), TRUE);//


    //running programs box
    box_running = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);//Makes a new box, puts it in the variable.


    //Active Programs notebook
    notebook_running = gtk_notebook_new();//Creates a new notebook and puts it into the variable.

    box_placeholder = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);

    gtk_notebook_insert_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook_running), GTK_WIDGET(box_placeholder), GTK_WIDGET(label_open), 0);//Inserts a placeholder tab into the running notebook.

    gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook_running), GTK_POS_BOTTOM);//Tells the running notebook to put its tabs on the bottom.



    //Main Notebook
    notebook_main = gtk_notebook_new();//Makes a new notebook, the thing with the tabs, and places it in "notebook_main".

    gtk_notebook_insert_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook_main), GTK_WIDGET(box_running), GTK_WIDGET(label_running), 0);//Puts the running box into the main notebook and names the tab with the running label. Places it withid 0.


    //Main Box
    box_main = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);//Creates and puts a new horizontal box into the "box_main" variable with "0" pixles spacing its contents.


    //Building the darn window
    window_main = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);//Creates and places the main window,"wood_GUI" into the variable "window_main".

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window_main), WOOD);//Names window_main after the latest version, defined by "WOOD".

    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window_main), 800, 480);//Window size in pixles (object, width, hight).

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window_main), 0);//Sets the border width of "window_main" to "0", making it as small as possible.

    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window_main), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);//Tells the "window_main" to always apear in the center of the screen.


    //Packing
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_running), GTK_WIDGET(notebook_running), TRUE, TRUE, 0);//Puts the running notebook into the running box lest it expand and tells it to fill the space. Also places it in the first slot.

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_main), GTK_WIDGET(notebook_main), TRUE, TRUE, 0);//In order, this selects "box_main" and places "nootebook_main" within it, left to right or top to bottom, depending on box orientation; it then sets its ability to expand if given extra space to "TRUE" and its directive to fill the space it is givin to "TRUE"; Finnally, it sets the spacing between sections in the box to "0".

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window_main), box_main);//Adds "box_main" to the "window_main" container.


    //Connect signals
    g_signal_connect(window_main, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);//This makes sure the program closes when the window is closed. No idea how it works.


    //Show what we made.
    gtk_widget_show_all(window_main);//Shows the window. All widgets within shown by default.


    printf("\n\nAbout to start GTK loop.\n\n");

    //Loop
    for(;;)//Forever...
    {

        //gtk_main_iteration_do(0);//Handle the next gtk event. 

        read(pipe[0], &xid, sizeof(xid));//Read the window id into xid from the pipe.

        //printf("\n\nAbout to run GTK loop.\n\n");


        if(xid != 0 && xid != check && xid != plywood)//If the xid is not 0, and not the same as the last one, and not the plywood window...
        {
            test = xid;


            printf("\n\nRead a valid id, it was %lf.\n\n", test);

            if(ftc != 0)//If this is not the first run...
            {
                socket = gtk_socket_new();//Creates a new socket.

                ev_box_socket = gtk_event_box_new();//Creates a new event box for the socket.

                box_socket = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);//creates a new box for the event box.

                gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(ev_box_socket), socket);//Puts the socket into the socket event box.

                gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box_socket), ev_box_socket);//Puts the socket event box into the socket box.

                gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_socket), GTK_WIDGET(ev_box_socket), TRUE, TRUE, 0);

                gtk_notebook_insert_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook_running), GTK_WIDGET(box_socket), GTK_WIDGET(label_open), 1);//Adds a pag with the prepared socket box and socket.

                gtk_socket_add_id(GTK_SOCKET(socket), xid);//Places the id into the socket.

                check = xid;//Sets thecheck to the previous id.

                gtk_widget_show_all(notebook_running);//Shows everything in the running notebook.
            }   

            else if(ftc == 0)//If this is the first run...
            {
                plywood = xid;//Sets the first window id recived as our window id.

                ftc = 1;//Sets second run.

                printf("\n\nJust had first run of valid ID.\n\n");

            }

            else if(ftc == 1)//If this is the second run...
            {
                gtk_notebook_remove_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(notebook_running), 0);//Remove the placeholder page in the running notebook.

                ftc = 2;//Set third+ run.

                printf("\n\nJust had second run of valid ID.\n\n");
            }

            printf("\n\nFinnished a run of valid ID.\n\n");
        }




        gtk_main_iteration_do(0);
    }

    printf("\n\nOut of the GTK loop, don't know how that happened.\n\n");

    //gtk_main();//This is the basic premade GTK loop.


    return 0;//Ends the main function.
}

//woodglue function
int woodglue(int argc, char **argv, int pipe[2])//This checks for events that relate to windows being created on the desktop.
{

    close (pipe[0]);//Close the input pipe since we won't be using it here.


    //Variables
    Display *dpy;//This will hold the default display identifier, neccisary for almost all x functions.
    Window root;//Declares a window variable called root for holding the window id of the root window.
    Window xid;//This will hold thewindow id for the windows that have mapped themselves to the display withen the root window.
    XEvent ev;//This is a structure for holding event passed to us by the X server.
    double test = 0;
    /* 
    For referance of the XEvent structure, some of its components are also structures. (Do not uncoment.) :

    typedef union _XEvent {
        int type;   // must not be changed
        XAnyEvent xany;
        XKeyEvent xkey;
        XButtonEvent xbutton;
        XMotionEvent xmotion;
        XCrossingEvent xcrossing;
        XFocusChangeEvent xfocus;
        XExposeEvent xexpose;
        XGraphicsExposeEvent xgraphicsexpose;
        XNoExposeEvent xnoexpose;
        XVisibilityEvent xvisibility;
        XCreateWindoEvent xcreatewindow;
        XDestroyWindowEvent xdestroywindow;
        XUnmapEvent xunmap;
        XMapEvent xmap;
        XMapRequestEvent xmaprequest;
        XReparentEvent xreparent;
        XConfigureEvent xconfigure;
        XGravityEvent xgravity;
        XResizeRequestEvent xresizerequest;
        XConfigureRequestEvent xconfigurerequest;
        XCirculateEvent xcirculate;
        XCirculateRequestEvent xcirculaterequest;
        XPropertyEvent xproperty;
        XSelectionClearEvent xselectionclear;
        XSelectionRequestEvent xselectionrequest;
        XSelectionEvent xselection;
        XColormapEvent xcolormap;
        XClientMessageEvent xclient;
        XMappingEvent xmapping;
        XErrorEvent xerror;
        XKeymapEvent xkeymap;
        long pad[24];
    }XEvent;
    */



    if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0x0)))//If the display does not return, 
    {
        printf("\n\nX couldn't connect to the display.\n\n");

        return 1;//return error.
    }

    root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);//Collects the id of the default root window.

    XSelectInput(dpy, root, SubstructureNotifyMask);//Tells the root window that we want to get events  that relate to changes in the substructure.

    printf("\n\nX connected to the display.\n\n");

    for(;;)//Forever,
    {

        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);//This throws the next event in the que int the "ev" structure thing.

        printf("\n\nThe x loop just ran.\n\n");

        if(ev.type == MapNotify)// && ev.xcreatewindow.parent == root)//If the event type is a notification of a window being mapped to the root window, and its parent is the root (as of right now, I am not sure that all the windows we are looking for have root as the parent, so that is disabled),
        {   
            printf("\n\nJust got a map notify event.\n\n");

            xid = ev.xcreatewindow.window;//place the window id of the created window into "xid".

            write(pipe[1], &xid, sizeof(xid));//write the id, however long it is, into the input stream, sending it to plywood. Unknown if this pauses the loop.

            test = xid;

            printf("\n\nJust sent the window id, it was %lf\n\n", test);

            xid = 0;
        }


    }//And then we loop to check the next event.

    return 0;//I assume we need this, but maybe not for X...
}




//Main Function
int main (int argc, char **argv)//Forks the program and sets up the i/o stream.
{

    pid_t pid;//This variable serves to identify the program during a fork, a value of 0 represents the child proccess, where 1 is the parent.

    int pipe[2];//This initializes the file stream for use between the two versions of the program.

    pid = fork();//Forks the program, creating an additional iteration with pid = 0

    if(pid == (pid_t) 0)//If this is the child proccess,
    {
        printf("\n\nChild started.\n\n");

        plywood(argc, argv, pipe);//launch the plywood function, passing the starting varibles as well as the file stream "pipe".
    }

    else if(pid == (pid_t) 1)//Else for the parent proccess,
    {
        printf("\n\nParent Started.\n\n");

        woodglue(argc, argv, pipe);//launch the woodglue function, passing the starting varibles as well as the file stream "pipe".
    }

    else
    {

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`GtkPlug` and `GtkSocket` widgets](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/PlugSocket.html), but beware that they will prevent your program from being cross-platform portable. Most windowing systems do not support this; only X does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I haven't had time to fiddle with things until recently. I think I'm close but have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong at this exact point in time. I'll post some code.